# Gulp-concat not working at all - writing all base files instead of one

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-concat

I'm pulling out my hairs on this one, everything seems to be OK - as docs stated

```
gulp.task('compress-js-inline', function () {
    let rtask = gulp.src([
        'templates/js/jquery-1.7.min.js',
        'templates/js/bootstrap.js',
        'templates/js/js.inline.js'
    ]);
    rtask.pipe(gulpuglify());
    rtask.pipe(gulpconcat('js.inline.min.js'));
    rtask.pipe(gulp.dest('templates/out/'));
    return rtask;
});
```

In my `templates/out` as a result I get `jquery-1.7.min.js`, `bootstrap.js`,`js.inline.js` and **no** `js.inline.min.js`
Tried switching pipes places but not working.

Everything is newest version from npm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to chain `.pipe` calls as follows:

```
gulp.task('compress-js-inline', function () {
  return gulp.src([
    'templates/js/jquery-1.7.min.js',
    'templates/js/bootstrap.js',
    'templates/js/js.inline.js'
  ])
    .pipe(gulpconcat('js.inline.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('templates/out/'));
});
```

Comment: Ok! Now I understand what I changed and what was not working! I assumed that objects are refferenced and need to be cloned as in PHP... Seems it's not a case in JS/Node!
Changing `rtask.pipe(gulpuglify());` to `rtask = rtask.pipe(gulpuglify());` did the trick!